# How to install kube-apiserver on centos?

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed `etcd` and `kubernetes` on centos, now I wanna install `kube-apiserver`. I installed `kube-apiserver` by `snap`.

```sh
sudo yum install epel-release 
sudo yum install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo snap install kube-apiserver
```

I start `kube-apiserver` with the guide by this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/).
Unfortunately, I got failed with `***error etcd certificate file not found in /etc/kubernetes/apiserver/apiserver.pem`. But I found that the certificate file exists, how to run the `kube-apiserver` successfully?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know the reason of your failure. But I suggest you to install kubernetes by `kubeadm`, it's a great `k8s` tool. If you install `k8s` by `kubeadm`, the `kube-apiserver` will be installed as a k8s pod. The guide to install kubeadm via this [link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-centos).
I run the command `kubectl get pods -A`,

```
[karl@centos-linux ~]$ kubectl get pods -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                          READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-64pt6                      1/1     Running   6          4d18h
kube-system   coredns-66bff467f8-xpnsr                      1/1     Running   6          4d18h
kube-system   etcd-centos-linux.shared                      1/1     Running   6          4d18h
kube-system   kube-apiserver-centos-linux.shared            1/1     Running   6          4d18h
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-centos-linux.shared   1/1     Running   6          4d18h
kube-system   kube-flannel-ds-amd64-48stf                   1/1     Running   8          4d18h
kube-system   kube-proxy-9w8gh                              1/1     Running   6          4d18h
kube-system   kube-scheduler-centos-linux.shared            1/1     Running   6          4d18h
```

`kube-apiserver-centos-linux.shared` is a kube-apiserver pod, it is installed successfully.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using standard tool such as [Kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm/) to install kubernetes on centos. `kubeadm init` will generate necessary certificates and install all the kubernetes control plane components including Kubernetes API Server.

Following this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) you should be able to install a single control plane cluster of kubernetes.

Kubeadm supports kubernetes cluster with multiple control plane node as well as cluster with completely separate ETCD nodes.